# Sending Notification Messages

Tags: 8

My team is working on a simple message notification using the [message stack](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180145) but a bit tricky to implement.

The goal is when a user is subscribed to content, a notification message will be delivered to the user's email address.

We are trying to follow [this steps](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180227), doing the configuration in the browser. But the last step, we think should be added manually in a certain file as mentioned in this [comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_notify/issues/2877870#comment-12322392).

**Questions:**

- Where should I add the code to properly send the message into email?
- Is there a need to create a custom module to achieve it?

Comment: In D7 this would be a peace of cake (using the Message stack, combined with Rules, and zero custom code). Sure you want to do this in D8?

Comment: `Where should I add the code to properly send the message into email?` Depends of when you would like to send the notification message. When a node is updated? When a new node is created? or both?

Comment: Yes, our site is running in D8.

Comment: @NoSssweat Its either, updated, created or both. Can you site one example, im not very sure which file I will append it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hooks go in the **.module** file, the only hooks that can also work in the **.theme** file are preprocess and alter hooks.

So if you want the message to be sent when a node is created or updated, use [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.4.x).

Create a custom module, lets call it "Send Message"

**send_message.info.yml**

```
name: 'Send Message'
description: 'Sends the message when a node of Content type Article is created or updated.'
core: 8.x
package: Message
dependencies:
  - message
type: module
```

**send_message.module**

```
<?php

use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
use Drupal\message\Entity\Message;

/*
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()
 */

function send_message_node_presave(NodeInterface $node) {

   if ($node->getType() == 'article') { // checks if content type is article
      $message = Message::create(['template' => 'foo_message_type', 'uid' => $node->getOwnerId()]);
      $message->set('field_node_ref', $node);
      $message->save();
      $notifier = \Drupal::service('message_notify.sender');
      $notifier->send($message);
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed response will try that and accept the answer once working.

Comment: Getting this error message `TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\message_notify\MessageNotifier::send() must be an instance of Drupal\message\MessageInterface, string given, called in /opt/app-root/src/modules/custom/send_message/send_message.module on line 14 in Drupal\message_notify\MessageNotifier->send() (line 48 of modules/message_notify/src/MessageNotifier.php).`

Comment: seems like it doesnt need to be a string

Comment: As per https://www.drupal.org/node/2180171 looks like you need to create a message of some template type.

Comment: Im actually trying two methods. I tried to insert the `$notifier` lines in insert node of `/message_example/message_example.module` which has already defined template and your steps(creating a custom module). but the output is the same, https://www.drupal.org/project/message_notify/issues/2936095. Message stack is really a bit complex to implement in 8. But its always nice to make something work.

Comment: be careful with hook_node_presave, any actions will process when node created or created.

Comment: @NoSssweat don' be surprised if some day (soon?) a competing answer using D8Rules will be added by "somebody" ...

Comment: this solution are the best when you want to create custom module and send custom email with template. tried the solutions and its working as it is! you can use it in user hook, node hook, comment hook for this solutions